# MySQL SELECT FROM WHERE COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, where-clause

Hi im looking for an MySQL Select that returns only that rows with doubled entries in column xxx

example:

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    4 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    5 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    6 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    7 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

Got This Table and i want to read out all entries thats name is listed more than once, 
my Query is not working cause it just shows entries with two times the name just once

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(name) AS count
    FROM table_xy   
    having count(name) > 1;
```

what i want to have returned:

```
+------+------+------------+
| id   | name |   count    | 
+------+------+------------+
|    3 | Jack |     2      |
|    4 | Jack |     2      |
|    6 | Zara |     2      |
|    7 | Zara |     2      |
+------+------+------------+
```

Is there a way to get that?

Comment: no thats not the result i want if i do group by name it will show me just one entry for each different name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery for your group by:

```
SELECT  x.id, y.name, y.count
FROM    table_xy AS x
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Name, COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM     table_xy
            GROUP BY Name
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS y
            ON y.Name = x.Name;
```

Alternatively you could use a self join with distinct if you don't need the count:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT x.ID, x.Name
FROM    table_xy AS x
        INNER JOIN table_xy AS y
            ON x.Name = y.Name
            AND x.ID != y.ID;
```

Or a self join with GROUP BY if you do need the count:

```
SELECT  x.ID, x.Name, COUNT(y.ID) + 1 AS count
FROM    table_xy AS x
        INNER JOIN table_xy AS y
            ON x.Name = y.Name
            AND x.ID != y.ID
GROUP BY x.ID, x.Name;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4eeb8/1)**

Comment: Prefer `USING (Name)` over `ON y.Name = x.Name` - I'm not sure if it applies to derived tables, but it's a good practice to have as not only does it reduce ambiguity ("Error: column X is ambiguous" or similar) but it also tends to make better use of indexes.

Comment: Also, since you're using `HAVING`, you can use the `count` alias rather than the `COUNT(*)` function - pretty sure MySQL optimises that away, but still, can't hurt.

Comment: Yeah that works perfect thank you,
and thx Niet the Dark Absol for that USING(Name) info, didnt know that either ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Do you have anything to substantiate the fact that `USING` makes `better use of indexes`? In [this case at least](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e197/2) the execution plans are identical. With regard to your other points, I think they are entirely subjective, and I personally dislike the inflexibility of the using clause, (i.e. you can only use the equals operator), this leads to a mix of `USING` and explicit predicates throughout a query, and I am a big fan of consistency.

Comment: @GarethD I'm afraid I don't have anything to substantiate that, sorry! I've just noticed better performance simply by changing between using `USING` and not using it. However, `USING` explicitly tells MySQL that the columns are equal, so for example `SELECT a FROM x JOIN y USING (a)` works whereas `SELECT a FROM x JOIN y ON x.a=y.a` results in `a` being ambiguous in the field list (and `SELECT x.a` doesn't communicate that feeling of sameness when reading the query)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT  x.ID, x.Name, COUNT(y.ID) + 1 AS count
```

FROM    table_xy AS x

INNER JOIN table_xy AS y

ON x.Name = y.Name

AND x.ID != y.ID
GROUP BY x.ID, x.Name;